Calculating bounds for probability of picking an element in sampling without replacement with perturbed uniform distribution
While working on some probabilistic simulations, I ran across a particularly interesting result. Let me start with that as context.
Let $X$ be a finite set, with $|X|=t$. Suppose we want to sample points from $X$ by going over each of them and picking them up with probability $p$ and not picking them up with probability $1-p$. Then what is the probability that a particular point $x_0$ is picked? Clearly it is just $p$.
But this is time consuming to do, so we should try simulating this with a little better expected speed-up. What we do is we sample a number $N$ from $\text{Binomial}(t,p)$. Then we pick up elements from $X$ uniformly and independently till we have $N$ distinct elements (basically sampling without replacement). Now what is the probability of $x_0$ being picked up?
Well, suppose we are picking up $k$ points. Basic probability says that $$\mathbb P(\text{$x_0$ picked}\mid N=k)=\frac{k}{t}$$ and hence by law of total probability, we get \begin{align*}\mathbb P(x_0\text{ picked})&=\sum_{k=0}^t\mathbb P(\text{$x_0$ picked}\mid N=k)\mathbb P(N=k)\\&=\sum_{k=0}^t\frac{k}{t}\binom{t}{k}p^k(1-p)^{t-k}\\&=\frac1t\sum_{k=0}^tk\binom{t}{k}p^k(1-p)^{t-k}\\&=\frac1tpt\\&=p\end{align*} Et voila! This experiment actualy simulates what we want to do!

Now to my question.
I want to look at a modification of this simulation. Suppose now that we are told that there is a distribution $\mathcal D$ over $X$, with the gurantee that for all $x\in X$ we have $$\mathcal D(x)\in \left(\frac{1-\epsilon}{t},\frac{1+\epsilon}{t}\right)$$ for some $\epsilon\ge 0$. Note that for $\epsilon=0$, we get back the uniform distribution.
We do the same experiment again and ask the same question. Pick a number $N$ from $\text{Binomial}(t,p)$ and then again do $N$ samplings without replacements.

What is the range of probabilities where $\mathbb P(x_0\text{ picked})$ lies?


I attempted to calculate this in the same way as previously. For simplicity, let $\mathcal D(x)=p_x$. The probability that $x_0$ was not picked in the first pick is $$1-p_{x_0}=\sum_{i_1\ne 0}p_{x_{i_1}}$$ The probability that it was again not picked up in the second pick is $$\sum_{i_1,i_2\ne 0}\frac{p_{x_{i_2}}}{1-p_{x_{i_2}}}$$ which comes from rescaling the probabilities after we have picked $x_{i_1}\ne x_0$. Continuing, we get finally \begin{align}\mathbb P(x_0\text{ not picked}\mid N=k)&=\sum_{i_1\ne 0}p_{x_{i_1}}\sum_{i_1,i_2\ne 0}\frac{p_{x_{i_2}}}{1-p_{x_{i_2}}}\sum_{i_1,i_2,i_3\ne 0}\frac{p_{i_3}}{1-(p_{x_1}+p_{x_2})}\cdots\sum_{i_1,i_2,\dots,i_k\ne 0}\frac{p_{i_k}}{1-(p_{x_1}+p_{x_2}+\cdots p_{k-1})}\\&=\sum_{i_1\ne 0}\sum_{i_1,i_2\ne 0}\cdots\sum_{i_1,i_2,\dots,i_k\ne 0}\prod_{j=1}^{k}\frac{p_{x_{i_j}}}{1-\sum_{\ell=1}^{j}p_{i_\ell}}\end{align}
Hopefully the last equality is correct (correct me if I am wrong). In any case, subtracting this from $1$ gives us our required probability.
We would now like to bound this first before plugging it in the law of total probability. This is where my problems start. I tried calculating an upper bound by putting the upper bounds for $p_{i_j}$ for the numerators and the the denominators, but the bound becomes negative/undefined (because of a division by $0$) in some cases. Still going forward and plugging that in the law of total probability formula results in a negative/undefined value, which is not really a good thing.
So my questions are : Is my question answerable in any meaningful way using my approach? Or is any other method preferable?
Thank you in advance for any insights.

The jumble of sums and products from the question look intimidating, but I think it can be made a lot simpler, at least for the lower bound.
You are looking for a lower bound and an upper bound for $P(x_0 \text{ picked} | N=k)$. We claim that the lower bound is achieved when all the non-$x_0$ are the same. That means $D(x_0)=\frac{1-\epsilon}{t}$ and $D(x_i)=\frac{1+\frac{\epsilon}{t-1}}{t}$ for all other $i$.
Now we compute the lower bound. Suppose $N=k$. The probability of not picking $x_0$ in the first round is $1-p_{x_0}$. Given this first event, there is one less of the other variables, so now the probabilities of the remaining non-$x_0$ variables sum to $\frac{t-2}{t-1}(1-p_{x_0})$. So the probability of not picking $x_0$ in the second round is $\frac{\frac{t-2}{t-1}(1-p_{x_0})}{\frac{t-2}{t-1}(1-p_{x_0})+p_{x_0}}=\frac{(t-2)(1-p_{x_0})}{t-2+p_{x_0}}$. Likewise the probability in the $i$-th round of not picking $x_0$ is $\frac{\frac{t-i}{t-1}(1-p_{x_0})}{\frac{t-i}{t-1}(1-p_{x_0})+p_{x_0}}=\frac{(t-i)(1-p_{x_0})}{t-i+(i-1)p_{x_0}}$.
In conclusion, $P(x_0 \text{ picked}|N-k)=\prod_{i=1}^k \frac{(t-i)(1-p_{x_0})}{t-i+(i-1)p_{x_0}}$ in the smallest case. The largest case is similar with some signs reversed.
Now we still need to argue that this is the worst case. It should be clear that in the worst case $D(x_0)=\frac{1-\epsilon}{t}$, so we are most concerned about the other variables. Suppose some $x_i$ is larger than the other non-$x_0$ variables. Note that in our calculation, the probability of not picking $x_0$ in each round always depended on the sum of the probabilities of remaining non-$x_0$ variables. Since $x_i$ has a slightly larger probability of being picked, there is slightly larger probability than usual of the sum of probabilities of the remaining variables to be smaller than usual. So we can decrease the probability of $x_0$ being picked by reducing the probability of $x_i$ a bit and giving it to the non-$x_0$ variable with the smallest probability.
This is not a formal proof but hopefully the idea is clear. Proving it formally would probably require some induction argument and explicitly showing that a small change can give a smaller probability of picking $x_0$ (or maybe you can do something with local minima/derivatives?). All of these I'll leave to the poster of the question because too much work.
Finally, about the upper bound: I think it should be achieved when the non-$x_0$ variables are as diverse as possible, meaning that as many of them as possible are either $\frac{1-\epsilon}{t}$ or $\frac{1+\epsilon}{t}$. In that way, we ensure that, if $x_0$ is not picked, at least we maximize the probability of picking $x_0$ in the next round. Calculating this explicitly is a bit more complicated (likely the easiest when $t$ is even), and again I'll leave it to the poster.
